# Stim detector error model to syndrome graph

Tags: error-correction, stim

How can I convert a Stim detector error model into a networkx/rustworkx weighted graph representing the equivalent syndrome graph?

I want it to test a possible method to introduce erasures in the high erasure rate regime, where the method described in [How do I perform an erasure error in stim?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/26582/how-do-i-perform-an-erasure-error-in-stim?rq=1) might be invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is you iterate over the instructions of the model, interpreting them as per [the spec](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/file_format_dem_detector_error_model.md). For example, when you encounter an `error` instruction you add an edge to the graph. There are other details like dealing with loops and tracking the detector index offset. Ultimately it's boilerplate code: not necessarily hard, but definitely tedious.

There's code that takes a `stim.DetectorErrorModel` and outputs a `networkx.graph` in the old pymatching glue code in sinter: https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/0da65e5b44e600e9ea04f02ec0154c56b010e133/glue/sample/src/sinter/_decoding_pymatching_v1.py#L88 . You will likely need to tweak it for your use case, e.g. adjust what it does with decomposed hyper edges. But it'll get you started.